# Is that possible to create our own server using TcpListener class with IIS being uninstalled?

Tags: .net, vb.net, network-programming, tcplistener

Is that possible to create our own server using TcpListener class with IIS being uninstalled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can listen for incoming TCP/IP connections with `TcpListener` and implement any protocol you want.

If you want to handle HTTP yourself a better approach might be to use [`HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) rather than implementing the HTTP protocol yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, TcpListener uses TCP/IP stack and has nothing to do with IIS, but if you are trying to create a WebServer using TcpListener, it'd be kind of waste of effort, don't you think?

Comment: +1 for answering. The reason is that to overcome hidden weaknesses in IIS.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What is the hidden weakness in IIS?

Comment: I can't reveal the weaknesses openly but a report being submitted to MS.